# Running e2e tests on Sauce Labs from Protractor on Travis

Tags: angularjs, selenium, protractor, saucelabs

So I have my open source project (https://github.com/ahmednuaman/radian) and I have some e2e tests that run fine locally using [Protractor](https://github.com/angular/protractor).

I've followed the [Sauce Labs docs](https://saucelabs.com/tests) and set up my [`.travis.yml`](https://github.com/ahmednuaman/radian/blob/feature-23-an/.travis.yml) accordingly. The tests run right to the point where Protractor tries to connect to selenium server on Sauce Labs, this is a brief snapshot of the error:

```
Running "exec:e2e" (exec) task
Using the selenium server at ahmednuaman-radian:06dd4e07-0f52-4fdf-be5e-389f2117bbf5@localhost:4445
>> 
>> timers.js:103
>> if (!process.listeners('uncaughtException').length) throw e;
>> ^
>> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
>>     at HttpClient.send (/home/travis/.nvm/v0.8.26/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/index.js:62:16)
```

Here's the full job log: https://travis-ci.org/ahmednuaman/radian/jobs/16250460

So the next thing I did was try to emulate this locally. I read the [Sauce Labs Connect docs](https://saucelabs.com/docs/connect) and eventually ran this in my terminal:

```
java -jar ~/bin/Sauce-Connect.jar USERNAME PASSWORD
```

Everything started fine, [exactly the same as on Travis](https://travis-ci.org/ahmednuaman/radian/jobs/16250460#L7294) but as I then ran my `grunt e2e` task (after updating the [`protractor.conf.coffee`](https://github.com/ahmednuaman/radian/blob/feature-23-an/test/e2e/protractor.conf.coffee) to match the Travis config locally) and recieved the same error as Travis had, here's a snapshot:

```
Running "exec:e2e" (exec) task
Using the selenium server at ahmednuaman-radian:06dd4e07-0f52-4fdf-be5e-389f2117bbf5@localhost:4445
>> 
>> /Users/ahmed/bin/node/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1542
>>       throw error;
>>             ^
>> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
>>     at HttpClient.send (/Users/ahmed/bin/node/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/index.js:62:16)
```

I had a google around but I couldn't find anyone else with this problem. So, is it my config? Is it a protractor/webdriver issue? Care to shed any light on this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Ok so after re-reading all the docs again I found that my `config.seleniumAddress` was incorrect as it was missing the `/wd/hub` path at the end; then I got a new error: it was complaining about my credentials.

After diving into Protractor's source I [found this doozy](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/runner.js#L151), it basically wiped out all the `sauce*` credentials if I specify a `seleniumAddress`, so I removed it from my config, tried again and it worked! Woop woop! Here's the Travis output just for fun: https://travis-ci.org/ahmednuaman/radian/jobs/16271613

So the way to get Protractor to run on Sauce Labs via Travis is to use these config options:

```
config.sauceUser = process.env.SAUCE_USERNAME
config.sauceKey = process.env.SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY
config.capabilities =
  'tunnel-identifier': process.env.TRAVIS_JOB_NUMBER
  'build': process.env.TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER
```

And **not** to add a `seleniumAddress`.

Comment: Alternatively, you can also enter these configurations in your gruntfile. Thanks, here is the aforementioned repo if it helps someone in the future; https://github.com/ahmednuaman/radian

Comment: Thanks! I was totally thrown by the credential wiping behavior also. Perhaps there should be a separate SO question/answer for this?